# Regarding Scanning record based on datetime

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Have a dynamo db table which has a column called 'created' which stores datetime in epoch format which i need to scan for archival.

I need to archive the records which are more than 30 days older from a DynamoDB table. However, date time field is in epoch format.

i used below code 
filterkey is the column 'created' & filter value os 'epoch' value of current date and time.
 connection.scan_table(FilterExpression=Attr(filter_key).lte(filter_value))

when I tried that above code although records are there its returning no records. may be the scanning method is not correct because I am comparing epoch date and time .
can someone help me on this. scanning table with epoch date time formt in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do scans at all. Try [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) instead.

> Time To Live (TTL) for DynamoDB allows you to define when items in a table expire so that they can be automatically deleted from the database.
>
> TTL is provided at no extra cost as a way to reduce storage usage and reduce the cost of storing irrelevant data without using provisioned throughput. With TTL enabled on a table, you can set a timestamp for deletion on a per-item basis, allowing you to limit storage usage to only those records that are relevant.
>
> TTL is useful if you have continuously accumulating data that loses relevance after a specific time period. For example: session data, event logs, usage patterns, and other temporary data. If you have sensitive data that must be retained only for a certain amount of time according to contractual or regulatory obligations, TTL helps you ensure that it is removed promptly and as scheduled.

Seems exactly like your case. TTL should be a `Number` attribute with a time in epoch format (just like you have). After the TTL your records will be deleted from the database when TTL comes. You can then listen for deleted records with [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and archive them. [Read more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html) about enabling the TTL.

Such event based, push approach will scale much better then scans.

Comment: We are trying to filter out using python code. and the column contains epoch datetime format. I need to filter out based on that column for the records which are 45 days older than the current date. If normal date time format we can use 'gte' or lte (greater than or less than) and filter out, But in  Epoch I am not sure.. Thats the reason for asking help.
Uts for archival utility via Python.

Comment: With TTL and streams you do not need to filter at all. When you create an entry, you should populate a TTL colums (let's say `expires`) to current date + 45 days. After 45 days passed the entry is automatically deleted. Here comes the stream. It listens for deletions and archives (whatever it means) those deleted records. This way you don't need scans, your architecture is event based and scales better.

Comment: Its really good idea though :) but but the table is getting used from so many months ..i think from past one year more than 80K records in it. I am not sure we can do it now for this ..... so thought of filter scan with epoch time which is failing.

Comment: also archival cost for the client ? means using this TTL service?

Comment: ["TTL is provided at no extra cost"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html). On the contrary: the more data you have in the table, the more money you loose on a scans because only a few from the scanned items should be archived.

Comment: Note that ["A FilterExpression is applied after the items have already been read; the process of filtering does not consume any additional read capacity units"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-FilterExpression). So, filtering happens after the scan. That means that to find a few expired records you'll have to scan all 80K and pay for that.

Comment: Thanks, one final question this TTL can be done now also ? it starts from next day ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't got the question… You can enable a TTL at any moment, even after the table was created.